# Laravel on Termux shows 419 Page Expired even with [at]csrf sintax

Tags: laravel-10, termux

I run a Laravel 10 that contains a simple form and I want to know every request value when the form is submitted. The project works well on Windows 10 and Ubuntu, but show error **419 Page Expired** when run on Termux 0.118.0 even with `@csrf` sintax in the form.
Any solution, please?
Thank you

*routes/web.php*

```
Route::get('/media/formulir',[MediaController::class,'formulir']);
Route::post('/media/hasil',[MediaController::class,'hasil']);
```

*app/Http/Controllers/MediaController.php*

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Media;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MediaController extends Controller
{
   
    public function formulir()
    {
        return view('media.formulir');
    }


    public function hasil(Request $request)
    {
        print_r($request['mytext']);
    }

}
```

*resource/views/media/formulir.blade.php*

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>The Title</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form method="post" action="/media/hasil">
        @csrf
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="mytext" class="form-label">My Text</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mytext">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="mypassword" class="form-label">My Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="mypassword">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

*.env*

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:xpI4cGKiMciT3YEdBwXOYo1JWraehpbkOckWH/YVCDs=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
# DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
# DB_PORT=3306
# DB_DATABASE=laravel
# DB_USERNAME=root
# DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailpit
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_HOST=
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

VITE_APP_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST="${PUSHER_HOST}"
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_PORT}"
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```